# How To Get A Specific list or item in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using `ArrayList<Model>` according to my model class

and My Model class look like this:

```
public class Model{
  String name;
  int age;

 public Model(){}
 public Model(String name, int age){
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 }
 //and getters and setters for name & age.
}
```

#### So I want to access only that list or item or that fields that contain a particular name

so I have a total of three lists one is `arrayList<Model>();` which have data second is

`crimeList<Model>();` and another is `normalList<Model>();`

so I want to store data to `crimeList<Model>();` who's name is `"joker"` , `"morris"`

and to `normalList<Model>();` who's name is not `"joker"` and `"morris"`

```
//can I do something like this

for(int i =0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
  if(arrayList.contans("Joker")){
    crimeArrayList.add(arrayList.get(thatContains("Joker")));
  }
}
//like this
```

And Output should be like this: if I print `crimeList` and `normal list`

```
Crime list [name = Joker, age = 29, name = Morris age = 30, name = Joker age = 30, name = Morris age = 20] //and if more people found 
//with these names then add also to crime List;
Normal List [name = James age = 18, name = Bond age = 18, name = OO7 age = 19] //and so on...
```

Can Anyone help me?
any answer or solution is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of criminal names:

```
List<String> criminalNames = Arrays.asList("Joker","Morris");
```

Assuming that you have list of data:

```
List<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new Model("Joker", 29));
        arrayList.add(new Model("Morris", 30));
        arrayList.add(new Model("Joker", 30));
        arrayList.add(new Model("Morris", 20));
        arrayList.add(new Model("James", 18));
        arrayList.add(new Model("Bond", 18));
        arrayList.add(new Model("007", 19));
```

Get the crime list:

```
 List<Model> crimeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Model model : arrayList){
            if(criminalNames.contains(model.getName())){
                crimeList.add(model);
            }
        }
```

Get the normal list:

```
 List<Model> normalList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Model model : arrayList){
            if(!criminalNames.contains(model.getName())){
                normalList.add(model);
            }
        }
```

Print results:

```
System.out.println("Crime list: " + crimeList);
System.out.println("Normal List: " + normalList);
```

A more elegant solution is to use Java stream API `stream().filter`:

```
List<Model> crimeList = arrayList.stream()
        .filter(model -> criminalNames.contains(model.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Model> normalList  = arrayList.stream()
        .filter(model -> !criminalNames.contains(model.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Model> crimeList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Model> normalList = new ArrayList<>();

    models.forEach(model -> {
        if (model.name.equals("joker") || 
            model.name.equals("morris")) {
            crimeList.add(model);
        } else {
            normalList.add(model);
        }
    })
```

If needed, you can use **contains** instead of the **equal** function.

If uppercase and lowercase letters are also important, use *toUpperCase()* or *toLowerCase()*

You can **also** use the stream:

```
  List<Model> crimeList=new ArrayList<>();
  List<Model> normalList=new ArrayList<>();

  crimeList=models.stream()
            .filter(m-> m.name.equals("joker") || 
                        m.name.equals("morris"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thank you also for a answer I will also try It